# SwiftUI Navigation backward to certain View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a NavigationView which have multiple layers of NavigationLink.

e.g. A1->A2->A3->A4->A5.

```
struct A1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("this is A1")
            NavigationLink("to a2", destination: A2())
        }  
    }
}
struct A2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("this is A2")
            NavigationLink("to a3", destination: A3())
        }  
    }
}
struct A3: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("this is A3")
            NavigationLink("to a4", destination: A4())
        }  
    }
}
struct A4: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("this is A4")
            NavigationLink("to a5", destination: A5())
        }  
    }
}
struct A5: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("this is A5")
            NavigationLink("to A2", destination: A2())
        }  
    }
}
```

However, this only stack another `A2()` up to 6th level instead navigate back to the second level.

I've been noticed there is a `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>` and `self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` to do the programally navigate back, but still can't find a way to do it multiple time at once.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following `NavigationLink` in  `A2`.

> `init(destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>, label: () -> Label)`
> Creates a navigation link that presents the destination view when active.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:isactive:label:)

Use the following `NavigationLink` in `A3` and `A4`.

> `init(destination: () -> Destination, label: () -> Label)`
>
> Creates a navigation link that presents the destination view.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s

In `A5`, use a `Button` instad of `NavigationLink`.

And pass `isActive` upto `A5`. Toggle `isActive` when the button is clicked.

In this example, **A2** is the view that you want to return to.

```
struct A2: View {
    @State private var isActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: A3(isActive: self.$isActive), isActive: $isActive) {TText("this is A2") }
        }
    }
}


struct A3: View {
    
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: A4(isActive: self.$isActive)) {Text("this is A3"))}
        }
    }
}



struct A4: View {
    
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: A5(isActive: self.$isActive)) {Text("this is A4"))}
        }
    }
}


struct A5: View {
    
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
                    self.isActive.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("this is A5")
                })
    }
}
```